# What Julia error 'Unknown dependency for GARCH: NLopt' means?

Tags: julia, julia-studio

Using Julia Studio (Win XP) and trying to add package DataFrames - how can the following error be resolved?

```
Unknown dependency for GARCH: NLopt
```

(How can I verify that a package was installed) Running `dv = DataArray([1,2,3])` says DataArray not defined. So it seems stuck.

Comment: can someone create a tag for julia-studio. I think it would be useful.

Answer (score 4):

You're using a rather old version of julia (0.1.x) and the GARCH package doesn't support it. Try installing a development version [from source](http://github.com/JuliaLang/julia) (it takes a bit the first time, but should be quite automatic) or try a [development binary](http://julialang.org/downloads/#beta).

Edit: Also, this issue may now be taken care of if you want to do `Pkg.update()` and try again.